# Code color code and highlighting for unity

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have just starting learning how to make games in Unity, using Visual Studio as the Script Editor, I see other people have their Code colour coded and it also has auto completion.

I've followed some tutorials online but nothing has worked for me.

what do I have to install to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

To add auto-completion you have to add the unity visual studio package. To add this package please type in your windows search field: "Visual Studio Installer" and then click at the visual studio version the button "change". After that, a new window opens in this window click the field with the unity package and then install this package. Now you have auto-completion in Visual Studio.

To add colors look this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_g1TyAGk6Lk& I really recommend this color theme.

Answer (score 0):

The Color Coding of Code can be found on the Tools>Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors. For example, you want to change the color for the Operators (+, -, /, *, etc.), you would need to find it in the Display items List and edit (found on the Right Side of the Display Items) the color of the foreground (the text itself), it's background or whether it is displayed in bold or not.

I believe that auto completion or IntelliSense is on by default as for what I have Experienced in switching from MonoDevelop to Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i think you're looking at a popular visual studio plugin called Resharper;

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

It also has a Unity3D plugin (for resharper) which adds full support. That's were the coloring and extra intellisense comes from.

You can see some sample pictures here; https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I found there are a few parts to this.
First you want to have Enhanced Syntax Highlighting installed, maybe you have it installed by default.
Also you want to have Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced, Editor Color Scheme set to Visual Studio 2019.
Then go to:
Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Text Editor
scroll to:
Identificator - set this to special color you want your Unity keywords in.

then scroll to properties starting with the prefix "User Tags - ..."
You want to change these to any color othen than the original setting.
That should allow your other colors to not be rewritten by the 'Identificator' color.
Hope this helps.